# parsing files/ Columns in Python

Tags: python, string, file, count

```
10:01:36 adcli
10:01:36 sshd[
10:01:37 adcli
10:01:37 adcli
10:01:37 sshd[
10:01:37 adcli
10:01:37 adcli
10:01:37 sshd[
10:01:37 sshd[
10:01:37 adcli
10:01:37 adcli
10:01:37 sshd[
10:01:37 sshd[
10:01:37 adcli
10:01:37 adcli
10:01:37 adcli
10:01:37 runma
10:01:37 runma
10:01:37 sshd[
10:01:37 adcli
10:01:37 adcli
10:01:37 sshd[
10:01:37 sshd[
10:01:37 adcli
10:01:37 adcli
10:01:37 sshd[
10:01:37 roots
10:01:37 sshd[
10:01:37 adcli
10:01:37 adcli
10:01:37 adcli
10:01:37 sshd[
10:01:37 adcli
10:01:37 adcli
10:01:37 sshd[
10:01:37 sshd[
```

Here is my approach:( I know it's not a complete but)

```
    import re
    i="sshd"
    j="apached"
    k="wexd"
    count_a=0;
    count_b=0;
    count_c=0;
    file=open("hex01.txt","r")
    for line in file:
       for datestamp in line[0:5]
            if line.match("datestamp"):
                   print    datestamp,m=line.count("sshd"),n=line.count("apached"),0=line.count     ("wexd"),t=m+n+0
```

This is the sample input data I am trying to process in Python. I know it's reasonably easy to get the output using bash but i am learning a Python and I feel it's reasonably tough to get the desired output. Any help will be appreciated, i even don't need a perfect code but the algorith amd the appropriate python's libraries are enough. The output should be

aprocess_count, bprocesscount, Totals

ex: `10:01:37 10,2,1,13`  - Meaning that 10 sshd, 2adcli and 1 roots from above log file

Comment: how exactly would you get 2 adcli from that file?

Comment: Sorry that was just a sample output, not a sample output from the file provided

Comment: I have spent reasonable time trying to understand the available libraries and methods associated with Python. I am very new to python. Here is my basic concept, I don't need a code , the approaches and algorithms works fine for me. import re
i="sshd"
j="apached"
k="wexd"
count_a=0;
count_b=0;
count_c=0;
#!/usr/bin/python
file=open("hex01.txt","r")
for line in file:
        for datestamp in line[0:5]
                if line.match("datestamp"):
                       print datestamp,m=line.count("sshd"),n=line.count("apached"),0=line.count("wexd"),t=m+n+0

Comment: add what you tried to your uestion

Comment: This is my first time asking the questions here, sorry for my ignorance , i didn't knew how to ask questions. Thanks!

Comment: @Ravi, I added an answer, for future reference always add the code you have tried. Also check out how to ask a good question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Padraic, Thanks for your suggestion and your answer. I will be spending more time to understand the code tomorrow. However, I still don't understand why do we need to change the entire file stream into key,value pairs ? In bash cat output.txt|sort|uniq -c|sort will certainly output equivalent. Also, the sum of the key values is missing is there any function to address this issue like adding summing up the values of each proceses?

Comment: @Ravi, I don't get what you mean by the sum is missing, the code produces a count for each process, as far as the key/values go this is python not bash you need some way to store the info and a dict is ideal for this.

Comment: @Padraic I absolutely agree dictionary should be the proper data structure for this kind of problem. I have been investing lot of time and resources to understand the different methods and functions in dictionaries. I have outlined the following algorithm to solve this. Does this works ?                                                    1. create_unique_dict_time

Comment: @Ravi, I cannot see your full I comment

Comment: @Padriac can you read in the following answer sections, sorry i am still getting used to with this site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dict.setdefault](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_setdefault.htm) adding a new dict when we see a new timestamp and increasing the `sshd` etc.. key value by 1 each time we see the key:

```
d = {}
with open("in.txt") as f:
    for line in f: 
        # split into time and sshd etc..
        time, res = line.split()
        # use setdefault so we get a new dict for each timestamp and set each new key's value to 0
        d.setdefault(time, {}).setdefault(res[:-1],0)
        d[time][res[:-1]] += 1

from pprint import pprint as pp
pp(d)
{'10:01:36': {'adcl': 1, 'sshd': 1},
'10:01:37': {'adcl': 20, 'root': 1, 'runm': 2, 'sshd': 10}}
```

You could also use a [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) dict:

```
from collections import Counter
d = {}
with open("in.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        time, res = line.split()
        d.setdefault(time, Counter())
        d[time].update([res[:-1]])
```

Comment: @Padriac, sum refers to sum of all the processes. In the previous example , if you see the output :10:01:37 10,2,1,13 13 refers to sum of all the processes 10+2+1, so the sum is still missing . You have a wonderful new year!

Comment: @Ravi, thanks, the sum is there it is 1,1 for 10:01:36 and 20,1,2,10 for 10:01:37, there is no 13

Comment: @Padriac, what i am explaining is we are still missing the sum of these keys; I also need a sum of all keys(process) of each row at specific time. 13 is the sum of 10+2+1 ; sorry for my poor articulation.

Answer (score 0):

```
1.create_unique_dict_time /*have no clue how to make this?
2. create_unique_dict_process /*
 for line in file.open("a.txt","r"):
     `time,process = line.split()
     create_unique_dic_time 
     create_unique_dict_process     
 for line in file.open("a.txt","r"):
    time,process=line.split()
      while time= {loop through each of the elements in 1.}
              if process={loop through each elements. in 2.}
               print time,[{element1,...}],sum{elements}
```

@Padriac, sum refers to sum of all the processes. In the previous example , if you see the output :10:01:37 10,2,1,13 13 refers to sum of all the processes 10+2+1, so the sum is still missing . You have a wonderful new year!